# Should we pass data in constructor or we should strictly stick to bundles to pass data from one fragment to another fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, constructor, bundle

I have seen usage of Fragment's constructor to pass data between the fragments(ex. new MyFragment(myData)) but I want to know if we should use that approach or not, the official google developer documentation mentions the usage of Bundle. I want to know what is the better approach and why? I am a beginner in android development so please feel free to guide. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bundles. When the fragment gets recreated, you get the bundle back. Arguments passed through constructor are "invisible" to the OS, and you lose them when the fragment is recreated.

Comment: Thanks @Shark for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Pass `Bundle` as arguments, extract them `onCreate()` ...

then you can use them with the Navigation library, too.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Martin Zeitler. Though I wanted to know that between both the approaches which one is preferable and why.

Comment: @JB08 I've already answer that question; custom constructors for `Fragment` are commonly useless, but aren't invalid either - so this merely depends what they're being used for, what actually is to be preferred. A generalization is by default always wrongful.